# How can I change the icon showed by the window manager in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to change the icon which is displayed for the emacs window (frame). For two different sessions (gnus and normal emacs editing) I want to have different icons. Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: You probably need to specify the OS if you want an answer.

Comment: The OS and the window manager, I'd say; this most likely cannot be done within Emacs, so you're going to have to shell out somewhere to do it if if can be done at all, and knowing which OS/WM will be necessary to know whether and how it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Emacs manual, node `Icons X`.  This is what it says about this:

```
By default, Emacs uses an icon containing the Emacs logo.  On
desktop environments such as Gnome, this icon is also displayed in
other contexts, e.g., when switching into an Emacs frame.  The `-nbi'
or `--no-bitmap-icon' option tells Emacs to let the window manager
choose what sort of icon to use--usually just a small rectangle
containing the frame's title.
```

On some window managers or platforms you might need to find another way to do it.